# JQuery tablesorter math widget with output widget

Tags: jquery, widget, tablesorter

I am using jquery tablesorter and was able to use the filter and math widget. I am now trying to export the table to csv with the use of the output widget and it's working fine except I cannot find a way to export the footer that uses the math widget. I have read the documentation in http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html but I can't find a way to do this. Is there any simple way to do this? Thank you in advance.

**Edit: Found Answer myself**

I don't know if it's a good one but it works. Instead of just putting the row with the total and average, that uses math widget, in the footer, I also added it on the last part of my table then set tr style="visibility:collapse". This way it became the last row in my table, when exported, but it's hidden so it would not create confusion to the user.

Comment: I have tried the output-dataAttrib but it only works for the header of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the output widget wasn't including the `tfoot` rows, so I added a new option `output_includeFooter`. This code change is currently available in the master branch of the repository.

Download the file: [widget-output.js](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/widgets/widget-output.js) (click on the `raw` button).

Or, download a zip of the entire repository (link on the [main page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter)).